# Query is not using view index instead it is using normal table Primary Key index

Tags: indexing, azure-sql-database, query-optimization, database-performance, database-indexes

I am developing a Power BI Report using direct query i.e every time my report is opened the query is being executed on my database and the returned rows will be displayed on the report.

I am using Azure SQL Database as the data source.

Below is my table structure from which I am fetching the data:

```
CREATE TABLE [reporting].[FactPaymentDetailsTable](
    [CheckPayId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PaymentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Department] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PaymentName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [TipAmt] [decimal](15, 4) NOT NULL,
    [PayAmt] [decimal](15, 4) NOT NULL,
    [BusinessDate] [date] NULL,
    [Rounding] [decimal](21, 5) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FactPaymentDetailsTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CheckPayId] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Now my report is sending the below query to display a visual:

```
SELECT SUM([t0].[Rounding])
 AS [a0]
FROM 
(
(Select * From reporting.FactPaymentDetailsTable)
)
 AS [t0]
```

This query is taking a bit longer as I am having a large amount of data in my table.

To optimize its performance I have created a view defined below:

```
create view [reporting].[TotalRoundingAmountView] with schemabinding
as
select SUM(rounding) as Rounding, COUNT_BIG(*) as CountBig
from reporting.FactPaymentDetailsTable
```

And created an index on the above view defined below:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [ix_RoundingTotal] ON reporting.[TotalRoundingAmountView]
(
    Rounding 
)
```

So now when I execute the query i.e being executed by my report i.e the below query the expected result is that the query should use the view index. However, when I am looking into the query execution plan it is showing that the table is still using the table Primary Key index.

```
SELECT SUM([t0].[Rounding])
 AS [a0]
FROM 
(
(Select * From reporting.FactPaymentDetailsTable)
)
 AS [t0]
```

Can anyone please help me out in this.

The exact same approach I have followed for my sales data and in that scenario, the query was using view index. I am not able to figure out why my query is not using view index in this scenario.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the execution plan may consider it's faster to use table's index instead of view's, have a try of this keyword: "WITH (NOEXPAND)" to force the execution plan to use view's index.

If more detailed info needed, [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-indexed-views-the-basics/) may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try adding a columnstore index instead of an indexed view.  Indexed views are great for making specific queries go faster but they can have large impact on locking and concurrency (specifically in your case) as every update to the table will need to update that view and specifically the same row on that view.  Columnstores and batch mode processing should give you a second path that has a more optimized execution engine for large data set queries where the storage structure is compressed and some answers are preaggregated for you.  Please give it a try and see if it works better for you.